# Android | RESTful + (SyncAdapter or AsynTask)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, rest

I am building an application that will communicate with a server through a RESTful api and I'm not sure which one to use (SyncAdapter/Asyntask). 
Basically, I have to update my SQLite database everytime the user logs in (in fact, I believe I could do without the SQLite dabase as the data in the Sever DB is very volatile and changes quickly). (the app would be holding on to old data)

Right now, I'm just saving data on local variables (arraylists) I don't mind then getting lost when the user leaves the app. Also, I'm making http requests using an Asyntask. Is this a good approach? I'm not really sure.

Is SyncAdapter a good fit for my use case? Should I use a SQLlite DB? despite the fact that I don't want to persist data in my app.

Thank you

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) which is very flexible and especialy designed for RESTful Http clients.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. checking it out!.